# Writing a custom router in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm refactoring my existing code-base for my API. I have a structure where there can be any amount of "lookup" parts in the url (eg. /api/{lookup1}/{lookup2}/.../{lookupN}) You can think  about it as a filepath from regular computer filesystems.

At the moment I just direct the request into APIView which breaks the url and does the lookup based on the request url. However, now I read more about DRF's routers and got wondering if I could rework this system using routers.

I have been studying routers now but couldn't really figure out if I could "intercept" the request, and then